# Unable to display an image using Amazon S3, why?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

With meteor, so in javascript, I try to display an image from AMAZON S3.
In the src property of the image, I put the access url to the mage provided by the AWS console, and it works if my image is public.
If I put it not public in AMAZON S3, it does not work.
So I ask S3 to send me the correct URL and I provided this URL to the src property of my image:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'mybucket', Key: 'photoPage06_4.jpg', Expires: 6000};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
console.log("URL", url);
document.getElementById('photoTest').src =url;
```

And there I have the error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)

Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour. If an image is set as private on S3, you can't view it publicly. This means you won't be able to view the image by setting it as the `src` property of an image tag or by pasting it into the address bar in your browser.

This is intentional since many people and companies use it to back up files, share files internally, etc. So they need the option to keep their files private. The way they create and access their private files is through the AWS APIs, not directly over the web.

So to answer your question, you need to make any images you want to display on your site public in S3.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
OK, I'll put all my images to post on the site in public. But does this mean that anyone can download them?
I do not like it too much!

Comment: Yes, anyone can download them. There is no way to prevent that. If an image is displayed on a website, it can be downloaded. If it wasn't downloadable, it wouldn't be displayable.

Comment: @yvanCoyaud don't forget to mark this answer correct.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your reply

Comment: Sorry, I do not find how to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @yvanCoyaud click the checkmark next to the answer.